How do I get a ProBook 640 G4 VFS495 to work on Kubuntu 23.10
On Kubuntu 23.10, my fingerprint won't detect. VFS 495 detected. lsusb output:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:706d Lite-On Technology Corp. HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

